# Boost 1.58.0 windows process.h error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, beginthreadex

I am trying to port my application to use boost 1.58.0 from 1.53.0
Getting this error while compiling in windows

```
\include\boost/interprocess/detail/os_thread_functions.hpp(495): error C3861: '_beginthreadex': identifier not found
```

`os_thread_functions.hpp` includes `<process.h>` but my application also has a header file named `process.h`.

I  guess `os_thread_functions.hpp` includes my application's `process.h` instead of Window's header and hence the error.

How do i force `os_thread_functions.hpp` to include the `process.h` from VS header files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> os_thread_functions.hpp includes  but my application also has a header file named process.h.

That should not have to be a problem as long as the include paths are well-managed.

In particular, you should

- Not add your "current" directory to the include paths (the current directory is implicitly searched)
- Include your header as `"process.h"`, not `<process.h>`.

This comes down to `#include <>` being for "system" or "third party" include locations. See [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)